# How to use Underscore.js filter with an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I have an object like so:

```
> Object
  > Rett@site.com: Array[100]
  > pel4@gmail.com: Array[4]
    > 0
       id : 132
       selected : true
    > 1
       id : 51
       selected : false
```

etc..

How can I use the underscore [`_.filter()`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) to return back only the items where selected === true?

I've never had the need to go down to layers with `_.filter()`. Something like

```js
var stuff = _.filter(me.collections, function(item) {
    return item[0].selected === true;
});
```

Thank you

Comment: Could you clarify the object format? It looks like a hash of arrays keyed to e-mail addresses?

Comment: that's correct, how can I clarify?

Comment: And you're trying to pull out items from the hash where *all* of the array elements have `selected == true`?

Comment: correct, just items with selected === true

Comment: Ok, still not quite sure what you're looking for but posted strategies for the two most likely cases :^)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to pull all array elements from any e-mail address where `selected` is `true`, you can iterate like so:

```
var selected = [];

for (email in emailLists) {
    selected.concat(_.filter(emailLists[email], function (item) {
        return item.selected === true;
    }));
}
```

If you only want to pull the arrays where *all* elements are `selected`, you might instead do something like this:

```
var stuff = _.filter(me.collections, function(item) {
    return _.all(item, function (jtem) { 
        jtem.selected === true;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, for the first answer, what is "email in obj" and "obj[email]" the object I have is called "emailLists" given that, can you update? thx

Comment: strange, i'm getting a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier "

Comment: Sure. `obj` should have been `emailLists`; `email` is just the key of each element in the object. Where's that error coming up? (I didn't test!) :^)

Comment: ok nice that fixed the error. selected is always coming back as '[]'

Comment: I did a console.log inside, and "console.log(item.selected === true)" is correctly being logged as either true or false. For some reason it's not making it to the selected var

Comment: ["for..in should not be used to iterate over an Array where index order is important."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Iterating_over_only)

Comment: this turns my object into an array.

Comment: @chovy if you need an object, you might convert your object to an array of `["key", "value"]` pairs, apply the filter, and zip the results up with _.object.

Comment: Instead of the innermost functions that `return item.selected === true`, Underscore also allows you to pass an object of the form `{selected: true}`. This is called an [iteratee shorthand](https://underscorejs.org/#iteratee).

Answer (score 5):

Underscore's filter method will work on an object being used as a hash or dictionary, but it will return an array of the object's enumerable values and strip out the keys. I needed a function to filter a hash by its values that would preserve the keys, and wrote this in Coffeescript:

```
hash_filter: (hash, test_function) ->
  keys = Object.keys hash

  filtered = {}
  for key in keys
    filtered[key] = hash[key] if test_function hash[key]
  filtered
```

If you're not using Coffeescript, here's the compiled result in Javascript, cleaned up a little:

```
hash_filter = function(hash, test_function) {
  var filtered, key, keys, i;
  keys = Object.keys(hash);
  filtered = {};
  for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    key = keys[i];
    if (test_function(hash[key])) {
      filtered[key] = hash[key];
    }
  }
  return filtered;
}


hash = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
console.log((hash_filter(hash, function(item){return item > 1;})));
// Object {b=2, c=3}
```

TL; DR: [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) is great!

Comment: I added the key in as a second parameter, as Underscore's `_.filter()` does. Hope that's cool! :)

Comment: `_.filter` for object with keys is just `_.pick`

Answer (score 1):

I have an object called allFilterValues containing the following:

```
{"originDivision":"GFC","originSubdivision":"","destinationDivision":"","destinationSubdivision":""}
```

This is ugly but you asked for an *underscore* based way to filter an object.  This is how I returned only the filter elements that had non-falsy values; you can switch the return statement of the filter to whatever you need:

```
    var nonEmptyFilters = _.pick.apply({}, [allFilterValues].concat(_.filter(_.keys(allFilterValues), function(key) {
        return allFilterValues[key];
    })));
```

Output (JSON/stringified):

```
{"originDivision":"GFC"}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Dexygen was right to utilize [_.pick](https://underscorejs.org/#pick) but a cleaner solution is possible because the function also accepts a predicate

> Return a copy of the object, filtered to only have values for the allowed keys (or array of valid keys). **Alternatively accepts a predicate indicating which keys to pick**.

(highlight is mine)

Here's a real life example I've used in a project

```
_.pick({red: false, yellow: true, green: true}, function(value, key, object) {
    return value === true;
});
// {yellow: true, green: true}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const obj = {
    1 : { active: true },
    2 : { active: false },
    3 : { active: false },
}

let filtered = Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, current) => {
    const currentEntry = current[1];
    const currentKey = current[0];
    //here you check condition
    if (currentEntry.active) {
      return {
        ...acc,
        [currentKey]: currentEntry
      }
    }
    return acc;
}, {})
```

There is a rule of thumb, if you need to achieve something really exotic look up into reducer it can solve almost all problems related to objects, it's a bit tricky to get used to it, but trust me thorough reading of documentation gonna pay off.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you want a simplest way

```
_.filter(me.collections, { selected: true})
```

Comment: This answer is partially correct; you can use `{selected: true}` as a predicate in Underscore, for example with `_.filter` or `_.some`. In this case, it is not the whole story because the objects with `{selected: true}` are embedded in a larger object.