# How to get entries between a price x and y?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, underscore.js

im using the current jquery ui slider with a range:
http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range

and the underscore.js
http://underscorejs.org/

so ive a minimum and a max which i send, after the user stopped to slide to a function:

```
currentSlide:function(){
    $('#slider').slider({
        range: true,
        min: min,
        max: max,
        values: [ vmin, vmax ],
        stop:$.proxy(this.afterSlide,this)
    });
},

afterSlide:function(event, ui) {
    console.log(ui.values[0]);
},
```

in the afterSlide function i get the min/max correctly, but i dont know how to use underscore.js to get all entries which have a price starting by this min and end by the max.

Examplearray:

```
var sample = {
    "response": {
        "things": [{
            "index": 0,
            "price": "10"
        },{
            "index": 1,
            "price": "15"
        },{
            "index": 2,
            "price": "60"
        },{
            "index": 3,
            "price": "10"
        },{
            "index": 4,
            "price": "100"
        }
        ]
    }
};
```

After im using the Slider i have the min/max [12,61] so i want to see all entries ONLY starting with a price between 12 and 61 $

```
var result = _.find(sample.response.things, min/max);??
```

I dont understand the _.range() function correctly to use it how i need, or to create a correct statement with the *.where/*.find() function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Underscore.js filter with an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697702/how-to-use-underscore-js-filter-with-an-object)

Comment: nope. its not dublicate because need a comparsion to get all entries between a range and not with a key/value pair

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just get the max and min values, and since this seems rather trivial I'd just iterate the object and check if the relevant value is within the range, and add it to a new object, no _underscore needed really, something like this:

```
afterSlide:function(event, ui) {
   var min = ui.values[0],
       max = ui.values[1],
     items = {};

    $.each(sample.response.things[0], function(key, val) {
        if (val.price > min && val.price < max) {
            items[val.index] = val.price;
        }
    })
},
```